# AWS Lambda / JNI - Trying to make it work with embedded native files

Tags: java, maven, jar, aws-lambda, java-native-interface

my console application (a Java Maven project) requires a JAR dependency which requires natives `*.so` files to work.

I'm under Linux and the only way I found to make my application work is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable with the absolute path of the native `*.so` files.

**My problem:** I have to convert my *console application* to an *AWS Lambda*, so I need to embed the native `*.so` files.

**Attempts:**

1. I put the native `*.so` files in Maven's *resources* folder of my project. But it didn't work.
2. I've changed my strategy by uncompressing my JAR dependency, put the native `*.so` files in the root, re-creating the JAR dependency with the `jar` utility (the inner architecture is ok). But it didn't work either:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.filepool.natives.FPLibraryNative.setLastError(I)V
    at ...
```

**N.B:**

- I thought `-Djava.library.path` would be similar to the exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, but `-Djava.library.path` doesn't work.
- When I decompile the JAR dependency I see a `static` block which has the `System.loadLibrary("somelibname");`, so putting the native `*.so` files into the classpath should have worked (I guess) but it doesn't

**Questions:**

1. Did I do something wrong?
2. Do you have any suggestions about how to make it work with an AWS Lambda?

Comment: "I put the native `*.so` files in Maven's resources folder of my project. But it didn't work." - What didn't work? Did you try to verify that the files exist within the Lambda function within the `/var/` or `/tmp/` directories?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with my *console application* first before to transform it into a Lambda, so it didn't work with my *console application* which has all the native `*.so` files in the *resources* folder. When I build my app (`mvn clean install`) the native `*.so` files are inside the JAR as I wish, but it still doesn't work and I have a simple `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. How am I supposed to put the native `*.so` files into `/var/` or `/tmp/` of the Lambda instance? If I could do that I wouldn't bother to embed those native `*.so` files into my JAR :D

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you leave JVM, you are lost when it comes to `java.library.path`. You have few options here.

Instead of linking with `-L/path -lsome_lib` you can use

```
-Wl,-rpath,/some/fixed/location -L/some/fixed/location -lsome_lib
```

Another option is to use explicit location of the library inside you Java code. Instead of using: `System.loadLibrary` you can use `System.load` and specify exact location of the library.

Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo031 where I show how to extract library from JAR file and load it inside Java code.